# Python: list strip overkill

Tags: python, list

I just want to remove the '.SI' in the list but it will overkill by remove any that contain S or I in the list.

```
ab = ['abc.SI','SIV.SI','ggS.SI']
[x.strip('.SI') for x in ab]
>> ['abc','V','gg']

output which I want is 
>> ['abc','SIV','ggS']
```

any elegant way to do it? prefer  not to use for loop as my list is long

Comment: Strip is given the set of leading and trailing characters to remove, not a pattern.

Comment: If they all need the last 3 characters removing: `[x[:-3] for x in ab]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why strip ? you can use `.replace()`:

```
[x.replace('.SI', '') for x in ab]
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'SIV', 'ggS']
```

(this will remove `.SI` anywhere, have a look at other answers if you want to remove it only at the end)

---

The reason `strip()` doesn't work is explained in the docs:

> The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

So it will strip *any* character in the string that you pass as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **remove the substring only from the end**, the correct way to achieve this will be:

```
>>> ab = ['abc.SI','SIV.SI','ggS.SI']
>>> sub_string = '.SI'

#       checks the presence of substring at the end
#                                   v
>>> [s[:-len(sub_string)] if s.endswith(sub_string) else s for s in ab]
['abc', 'SIV', 'ggS']
```

Because `str.replace()` (as mentioned in [*TrakJohnson's answer*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44733877/2063361) removes the substring even if it is within the middle of string. For example:

```
>>> 'ab.SIrt'.replace('.SI', '')
'abrt'
```

Answer (score 2):

use this `[x[:-3] for x in ab]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` instead of `strip` and get the first element:

```
[x.split('.SI')[0] for x in ab]
```